# close modal by clicking anywhere on the screen, not only the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code which makes it possible to open a modal by clicking on a button and to close it again by clicking on the same button. I would like it to be possible to close the modal by clicking anywhere on the screen, so not just this button.

I found a lot of pieces of code online on how to do this, but since I am a beginner with JavaScript it is very hard for me to incorporate new pieces of code within my own and make it work. Can someone help me solve this, and explain my how I and where I need to add/change lines in my existing code?

Here is the link to see how the modal works right now (button top right of the screen):
https://carbonrollercoaster.bsqd.me/

**JavaScript**

```
const bf = document.querySelector('#botsquad-frame');

let el = document.createElement('div');

el.setAttribute('id', 'mijnKnopje');

const inhoud = `
<div class="info-content">
  <p1>INFORMATIE: <br>            
By participating within this chat, you accept that some of the answers you give will be displayed on one of the screens within the installation.
<br><br>
HOW TO:<br>
Go in conversation with Nostos and Algia, ask them questions and discuss multiple topics. </p1> 
</div>
<div class="info-section">
  <a role="button" class="knopje info-button" style="background-color:mediumpurple">
    <div class="info-label">!</div>
  </a>
</div>
`;

el.innerHTML = inhoud;

bf.appendChild( el );

const mijnKnopje = document.querySelector('.knopje');
const mijnInfo = document.querySelector('.info-content');

mijnKnopje.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //mijnInfo.style.display = 'block';
  //mijnKnopje.style.backgroundColor = 'fuchsia';
  mijnKnopje.classList.toggle( 'active' );
  mijnInfo.classList.toggle( 'active' );
  
  let inputField = document.querySelector('.chat-input');
  if ( mijnInfo.classList.contains( 'active' ) ) {
    inputField.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    inputField.style.display = 'revert';
  }
} );
```

Comment: -> Add click event to your `mijnInfo` ... there you can toggle classes, too.

Comment: @skobaljic Thank you for the answer! How should I write this within the code? I am really bad at this sorry, hope you can help

Comment: The OP might consider handling the `click` event on `document.body` level. If the `event.target` is not part of the `.info-content` classified element or originates from within or is equal to the `.knopje` classified close button then one wants to close the modal.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

Here's a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to work with.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function createOrDestroyPopupDummy(create) {
  const inhoud = `
    <div id="popup">
      <h3>INFORMATIE</h3>            
      <div>
        Als je in deze chat meedoet, kunnen antwoorden die je 
        geeft door anderen worden gezien
      </div>
      <h3>HOW TO</h3>            
      <div>
        Vraag Nostos and Algia van alles of discussieer met ze 
        over wat dan ook.
      </div>
      <div>
        <button id="closeInfo">Gezien!</div>
      </div>
    </div>`;
   const popupOpen = document.querySelector(`#popup`);
   const createBox = () => document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, inhoud);
   const destroyBox = () => popupOpen && popupOpen.remove();
   return create ? createBox() : destroyBox();
}

function handle(evt) {
    // show 'popup'
    if (evt.target.id === "info") {
      return createOrDestroyPopupDummy(true);
    }
    
    // do nothing if within the box and not clicked button#closeInfo
    if (evt.target.id !== `closeInfo` && evt.target.closest(`#popup`)) {
      return;
    }
    
    // otherwise destroy the 'popup'
    return createOrDestroyPopupDummy();
}
```

```css
#closeInfo {margin-top: 0.5rem;}
#popup {
  border: 2px solid green;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #999;
  width: 75vw;
  padding: 0.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%,-50%);
}
#popup h3 {
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.1rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="info">Info</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the only problem is that I since i am working with Botsquad I can't change or add HTML, I can only work with CSS and JS

Comment: Hi @sachava, the html is quite irrelevant here (just exemplary), it's about the way you handle the click event

Comment: But created a perhaps more instructive example for you (in dutch ;)

Comment: Hi @Kooilns thank you so much, this makes it super clear!

Answer (score 1):

You could add another event listener for the whole `div-info-content` aka `const mijnInfo` and remove the `active` class when clicked:

```js
const mijnInfo = document.querySelector('.info-content');

mijnInfo.addEventListener('click', () => {
  mijnKnopje.classList.remove( 'active' );
  mijnInfo.classList.remove( 'active' );
  document.querySelector('.chat-input').style.display = 'revert';
});
```